# TeXworks: How to add a word to the spell checker dictionary?

Tags: spelling, texworks, dictionaries

I use TeXworks to write my documents. The spell checker tool works nice, but I'd like to add some words to the dictionary, but I can't find a function for that.

So how can I do that?

Comment: You may want to use a spell checker on your title `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: You are my spell checker ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TeXworks uses a spell checker called [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/), an engine which is also used e.g. by OpenOffice:

Each dictionary consists of two files with the extensions `.dic` and  `.aff`. Where these are located depends on your TeXworks installation, on my system (TeX Live 2010, Windows), they are in the directory

`C:\Users\<user name>\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\dictionaries`

Adding words to the dictionary is quite simple: As the `.dic` file is a plain word list, you can just add new lines with your own words. If you want the system to recognize different word forms, too, you have to deal with the `.aff` file - see [this explanation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries) for more details. However, simply changing the word list should be enough in most cases.

Comment: For MikTeX and Windows 7, the directory is

    C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\<MiKTeX version>\TeXworks\<TeXworks version>\dictionaries

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33139/how-to-configure-the-dictionary-path-for-texworks-tex-live-2011-portable

Comment: This solution is not so convenient. TeXworks should add this feature to their good editor.

Comment: For MikTeX and Windows 7, actually, the directory is C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\hunspell\dicts

Comment: As stated in [TeXworks wiki > Obtaining dictionaries](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/SpellingDictionaries)

`Windows
To find the correct folder, use "Help -> Settings and Resources...", navigate to the "Resources" folder given there, and finally put the spelling dictionaries in the dictionaries folder (if it doesn't exist, create it). `

Comment: Keep also in mind, if you might update the dictionary package via the package manager, your custom entries will be lost, so do not forget to backup.

Comment: @escalator Is there any way to save the ignore word list to a safer place so that the customized dictionary won't get lost after upgrades? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to install the dictionary `PT_EU` as follows:

I opened the TeX works went to `Help` -> `Settings and Features` and clicked `C:/Users/Abilio/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/TeXworks/0.4`

After downloading the dictionary did `PT_EU` http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/dictionaries site, downloading a file. Otx. then open this file with 7-zip, and copied the folder "Dictionaries" folder to the 0.4.

Then I copied the entire folder TeXworks (`C:/Users/Abilio/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/TeXworks/`), to the following path `C:/Users/ Abilio / AppData / Local /`. Then I reopen the TeXworks, and the dictionary was already there and it worked.

I have windows Vista 32-bit.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) [Diabonas' answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11861/5872) already points to the need of installing the dictionary files in the first directory you mentioned. Why would you need to move the entire TeXworks folder? Doesn't it break the MikTeX tree (for updates and such)?

Answer (score 3):

In a MiKTeX 2.9 / Windows 8 context, the file to modify turned out to be

```
/Users/(username)/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/hunspell/dicts/en_US.dic
```

There was no problem editing it with a Unix-style editor within Cygwin.
The file has a word count at the beginning, but it did not seem necessary to increment the word count when adding new words. I presume the word count is used for storage allocation when the file is loaded. I added new words in alphabetical order.

The remark above about making a backup is right on!

Answer (score 0):

[Windows 7 Ultimate x86, TeXworks Version 0.4.5 r1280 (MiKTeX 2.9)]

I couldn't get my dictionary to be recognised in the `c:\Users\<username>` folder structure.  So, instead, I copied the `.dic`, `.aff` files directly into the `hunspell\dicts` sub-folder of my MiKTeX install (I have it in `c:\Program Files\LaTeX`) and that worked.

I then followed diabonas' advice about adding my own words to the `.dic` file, but they weren't immediately recognised by TeXworks as valid words.  I tried opening TeXworks a few times to see if it would finally recognise my changes, but to no avail.  The following worked for me in the end:
1)  I deleted the `.dic`, `.aff` I had copied in to the install folder (as explained above),
2)  I opened TeXworks to confirm my dictionary was no longer available.
3)  I added the new words to the original `.dic` file I downloaded (in the download folder I chose),
4)  I then copied the edited files back in the `hunspell/dicts` folder as stated above.
5)  I went back to TeXworks, and it was all good now.

I can't explain why making the edits directly in the `hunspell\dicts` folder would not work.  Perhaps something to do with caching or they get compiled.  I did not try to reboot my OS since I thought that was not necessary.

Cheers,
Nap

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but with OS X Yosemite. I accidentally caused the built-in OSX spelling dictionary (which is what many LaTeX editors use) to incorrectly learn a misspelled word. By directly editing the text file at `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` you can customize the editor to ignore common LaTeX syntax and to add custom words to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I am using TeXworks 0.6 at Windows 10.

It seems that TeXworks looks for dictionaries in two places,

```
C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/TeXworks/0.4
```

and

```
/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/hunspell/dicts/
```

I have added the same .dic and .aff files in both locations and I get two options for each language [image: double entries for dictionaries].

The number in the first line of the .dic files is the word count. If you add words and do not update the word count, my guess is that the last few words (after the word count) will be ignored. (I haven't tested it though). If you remove the number of words, all the words will be ignored (the dictionary will appear as an option though).

Answer (score 0):

In Arch Linux is very simple:

After installing hunspell:

```
sudo pacman -S hunspell
```

Installing English language spellchecker:

```
sudo pacman -S hunspell-en_US
```

and for the Spanish language spellchecker:

```
sudo pacman -S hunspell-es_es
```