# How to configure the dictionary-path for TeXworks @ TeX Live portable?

Tags: installing, texlive, texworks, spelling, dictionaries

I want to use spell-checking with TeXworks under TeXlive (portable) under Windows XP.

1. Is it possible to use the dictionaries of Mozilla, e.g. `en-GB.aff`
   and `en-GB.dic`?
2. Where do I place the dictionaries? Maybe C:\TeXlive2011\tlpkg\texworks\dictionaries\ ?
3. How do I configure TeXworks to use these dictionaries?

a) adding `TW_DICPATH=C:\TeXlive2011\tlpkg\texworks\dictionaries\` to `texworks-setup.ini` did not work

b) adding it in `TeXworks > Preferences > Typesetting > Paths` did not work

c) adding it in `Start > configuration > control > system > expanded > environmental variables > user variables` did not work

d) `... > system variables` did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An e-mail of Stefan Löffler from the TeXworks team was forwarded to me. Translated into English it says:

> I want to start by saying that the version of TeXworks, which is
>   included in TeXLive  (and other TeX distributions), is sometimes
>   modified  (for example, to adapt the paths to the respective
>   distribution). [...]  Yes, TeXworks supports [.dic and .aff] file
>   formats (with the hunspell library). [...]  Typically, the files
>   should be installed into the resource folder of TeXworks.  By default
>   this is `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\TeXworks\` (see 
>   http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Locating_and_customizing_TeXworks_resources),
>   but as mentioned, I suppose TeXLive moved it elsewhere.  From the
>   comments on http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/SpellingDictionaries 
>   I deduce that it is `C:\TeXlive2011\texmf-config\texworks\` (i.e., the
>   dictionaries should be placed into 
>   `C:\TeXlive2011\texmf-config\texworks\dictionaries`). To be safe, you
>   can try the menu item  "Scripts > Scripting TeXworks > Show Scripts
>   Folder" and  then navigate to the parent folder.
>
> The `TW_DICPATH` environment variable is *only supported on Linux*.
>
> Please also note that you must restart TeXworks to update the
>   dictionary list.

Therefore:

ad 1.: Yes, it is possible to use those dictionaries.

ad 2.: 
For **TeXlive2011** portable: 
To find out where to place the dictionaries, in TeXworks call 
`Scripts > TeXworks skripts > show scripts directory` (or whatever the menus are named in English). 
In that directory create a subdirectory dictionaries and copy the dictionaries in that 
dictionaries directory. 
(Possibly `C:\TeXlive2011\texmf-config\texworks\dictionaries`, depending where TeXlive was installed.)

For **TeXlive2012** portable: 
In TeXworks call `Scripts > TeXworks skripts > show scripts directory` (or whatever it is in English). 
Go to its parent directory. There should be directories "completion", "configuration", "scripts" (of course), "translations", and "TUG" inside. In that directory create a subdirectory "dictionaries" and copy the dictionaries in that dictionaries directory. 
(Possibly `C:\TeXlive2012\texmf-config\texworks\dictionaries`, depending where TeXlive was installed.)

For **current, non-portable TeXworks** ChrisS provides the correct answer at 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238852/6865.

ad 3.: Exit TeXworks. When the programme is started again, the dictionaries should be available. 
Go to the menue "Edit > Options > Editor > Language for spell check" and choose a language.
Go to the menue "Edit > Spell check" and choose a language.

Answer (score -1):

Creating a folder called `dictionaries` and placing the `.dic` and `.aff` into it in the below path works on Windows:

```
%userprofile%\.texlive2011\texmf-config\texworks
```

Comment: That only works, if (by chance) `%userprofile%\.texlive2011\texmf-config\texworks` is the scripts directory. In my installation it is not, and therefore that does not work.

Answer (score -1):

1. Downloaded en_GB.zip from Open Office
2. Opened up contents into a new sub-folder 'dictionaries' within %userprofile%.texlive2011\texmf-config\texworks
3. Restart Texworks

This has nothing to do with the scripts folder. Copying the en_GB.zip contents to scripts folder had no effect.

Comment: `TeXlive2011\texmf-config\texworks` *is* my scripts folder, and creating `\dictionaries` there and placing the en-GB.aff and en-GB.dic there did indeed solve my problem. From your "%userprofile%.texlive2011" I assume that your answer might not relate to Windows XP?

Comment: If you had read my question and answer, you would have noted that I did not talk about `en_GB.zip` but `en-GB.aff` and `en-GB.dic`.