# TeXLive 2011 and updmap

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

Well, I'm trying to install and configure TeXLive 2011 on Windows XP. As usual, a nightmare :-(. After six or seven attempts, it seems I've managed to do it but when trying to update font maps, I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't locate TeXLive/TLUtils.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /tlpkg  
C:/Aplicaciones/TeXLive/tlpkg/tlperl/lib c:/aplicaciones/TeXLive/tlpkg 
/tlperl/lib .) at c:/Aplicaciones/TeXLive/texmf/scripts/tetex/updmap.pl
line 18. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Aplicaciones/TeXLive/texmf
/scripts/tetex /updmap.pl line 18.
C:\Aplicaciones\TeXLive\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:575: command failed with
exit code 2:
perl.exe c:/Aplicaciones/TeXLive/texmf/scripts/tetex/updmap.pl -nohash
-enable Map=courier82.map
```

(Here, courier82 is a map of my own.)

Update. I've installed both TL2010 and TL2011. With the former updmap runs smoothly, with the latter fails.

(Edited to remove unnecessary comments. For the “solution”, see below.)

Comment: I'm not using TeXLive so I can't help you with your actual problem. But if the windows installer fails I would suggest: Either go to the TeXLive list and ask for help how to debug it or install miktex instead. Using a linux version to get a windows version is bound to give problems e.g. if it makes assumptions on folder structures or system tools. (Imho the message means that perl is missing. As far as I know the linux version doesn't come with a perl as perl is present on every linux.)

Comment: @Ulrike. Thanks. Perl is not missing, and tlmng worked. I had a similar problem before (already existed in TL2010) and IIRC it's a bug in Perl, which had problems with XP.

Comment: Yes you are right rereading the message I think perl is working. But it seems not to be able to find TLUtils.pm.

Comment: Installing TL2011 on XP should work. But you should _really_ upgrade your Windows.

Comment: Did you get TeXworks working with dictionaries? If so, please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33139/6865 and maybe provide an answer?

Comment: @Stephen I'm sorry I'm not using TeXworks, but I presume there is something wrong in the tlpkg stuff.

Comment: The times I've seen this problem it has either been the user having done a mistake when manually editing their PATH variable. Or some odd anti virus/firewall stuff.

Answer (score 3):

At last! What I've done is: (1) to copy both TL2010 and TL2011 to the hard disk, (2) to install them using the installers for Linux (with an Ubuntu live CD), (3) to replace many files in TL2010 by those in TL2011 (the whole texmf-dist, selected directories from textmf-* and some binaries, mainly tex engines), (4) to rebuild formats (of course). I presume further fine-tuning will be needed, but at least things are working. IIR, I've installed and uninstalled in just three days almost a million files :-(