# Problem with updmap

Tags: errors, updating

I'm running into a problem similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33457/texlive-2011-and-updmap).

I'm running Arch Linux and have installed TexLive from their repository. I noticed that I had some configuration files (texmf.cnf and updmap.cfg) that needed to be updated, so I diffed them and updated the relevant sections. In the case of updmap, it was simply adding some kanji font maps to the file.

Then, I thought I should run updmap since I changed the config. I got this:

```
$ updmap
Can't locate TeXLive/TLUtils.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /tlpkg /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl .) at /usr/bin/updmap line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/updmap line 18.
```

I checked for TLUtils.pm and found it:

```
$ locate TLUtils.pm
/usr/share/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm
/var/lib/texmf/arch/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm
```

I don't know where `@INC` (sounds like the TL path?) is defined and thus don't know where it gets told where to look for TLUtils.pm.

The line 18 referenced is this:

```
use TeXLive::TLUtils qw(mkdirhier mktexupd win32);
```

I'm guessing some things got moved around during some update and perhaps some path is still referencing some now non-location. How might I correct this?

Comment: What does `which updmap` say?

Comment: Both `updmap` and `updmap-sys` are in `/usr/bin/`. (Actually just noted that the error above says that: `failed... at /usr/bin/updmap line 18`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after your answer I understand what is going on.

TL binaries use their locations to search for their libraries.  If you installed TL in `/usr/local/texlive`, they are in `/usr/local/texlive/YEAR/bin/ARCH`, and look for their libraries in locations like `../../tlpkg` etc.  However, your `updmap` is from the system vendor installation (or maybe you copied it there instead of symlinking), and its location is `/usr/bin/`, so `../../tlpkg` gives the directory where nothing is found.

Add the path to TL2011 binaries in the *head* of the search path, like `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH`.  Or just symlink the new binaries to `/usr/local/bin`: usually this directory is searched before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I don't have a /usr/local/texlive directory... Should I? Arch Linux provides the Arch Build System so you can build from source. Here's the [default build script](http://pastebin.com/g9KtmbBw) for texlive-core (how the binary installs from the repo by default. No references to /usr/local that I see.

Comment: I might be muddying waters since Arch does this differently than the TL default or other distros... I posted on Arch forums as well and will post the answer here if I get it. My apologies if this is a source of confusion.

Comment: Well, you can either take the fresh binaries from TL and install them using `tlmgr`, or patch the build script for Arch linux.  I'm afraid in the latter case the question belongs to an Arch linux forum since it covers a specific vendor-related topic.

Comment: Using symlinks requires to reset them all when there's a major update of TeX Live (2011->2012, for instance). With the `PATH` method only that needs to be updated.

Comment: I'll look into just installing via tlmgr. Out of curiosity... where *does* the @INC path get defined? Perhaps I can at least try and track down a config that might be out of date and point it to the right place?

Comment: Well, if you say `perl -V`, you get the default @INC.  On my machine it is  @INC:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.10
    /usr/share/perl/5.10
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    .
However, if you look into `updmap`, you can see there the lines, that  add directories to @INC: 
BEGIN {
  $^W=1;
  chomp($TEXMFROOT = `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT`);
  unshift (@INC, "$TEXMFROOT/tlpkg");
}

Comment: @egreg `tlmgr` takes care of updating symlinks if this option is chosen.

Comment: @Boris But in `/usr/bin`, IIRC (which is not very good, as the system package manager may have different ideas when installing something that requires TeX).

Comment: @egreg The usual idea is that `/usr/bin` is for system binaries, while `/usr/local/bin/` is for something your sysadmin installed from the Internet.  Accordingly TeXLive can be compiled "as TL" (binaries in `/usr/local/texlive/YEAR/bin/ARCH` with optional symlinks to `/usr/local/bin`) or as a part of a system distro (binaries in `/usr/bin`, `TEXMFROOT` defined in a special way).  Nobody but system integrators should use the second option - and they should know what they are doing.