# How to add Spell Checker to TeXworks

Tags: texworks, spelling

I installed TeXworks and I was trying to install a spell checker but I couldn't. I installed OpenOffice but nothing changed, the combo-box of spell checkers in TeXworks is empty. I am working on Windows.

Comment: Did you install the OpenOffice.org dictionaries into TeXworks as described in [the manual](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5iVT8Q7W44pQkRFVG5mQkt0S1U&tid=0B5iVT8Q7W44pMkNLblFjUzdQUVE)?

Comment: Thanks .. The manual is really useful and it worked perfectly. can u post it as an answer

Answer (score 110, accepted):

As per the [TeXworks manual](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5iVT8Q7W44pQkRFVG5mQkt0S1U&tid=0B5iVT8Q7W44pMkNLblFjUzdQUVE), the procedure to install spell checking dictionaries in TeXworks is as follows.

1. Download the dictionary corresponding to your desired language from the [OpenOffice.org extensions site](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/search?f%5B0%5D=field_project_tags%3A157).
2. Change the file extension of the downloaded file from `.oxt` to `.zip` and extract the files with your archive utility of choice.
3. Open TeXworks and select `Settings and Resources` from the `Help` menu. A dialog window will open with a link to the TeXworks resources folder.
4. Click the link to open the resources folder. If there is no `dictionaries` subfolder there yet, then create it now. Open the (possibly newly created) `dictionaries` subfolder.
5. Copy the `.dic` and `.aff` files from the downloaded `.zip` file to the `dictionaries` subfolder.
6. Close and reopen TeXworks. The dictionaries should be listed under the `Spelling` item in the `Edit` menu.

Comment: I have the same problem, but the answer given above shows that we are still in the software Stone Age. I can’t do any of those things recommended; the installer program should do all this for me. What’s wrong with you programmers?

Comment: It works perfectly!!! Thank you! :-)

Comment: @G.'tHooft that's such a harsh comment about a free and open source software most likely developed with love and lots of free time. Pointing out issues is very useful and feedback always welcome but you should watch out on how you formulate things because you sound ungrateful. Any additional feature has an initial cost as well as maintenance cost I'm sure it's only a question of time.

Comment: OK, I’m sorry to have been offensive, there are many very good things about TeX and LaTeX to be mentioned, let me be clear about that. Also, yes indeed, they are free while many other applications are expensive and do’t work so well.

Comment: But I thought that it should be obvious and not at all understood as a “harsh comment” that we are still in the Stone Age.  How long ago did the first TeX see the light? Where will we be 50 years from now? I can see possible avenues for improvement everywhere, in particular the user interface of software. Please continue the good work with new smart ideas.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, it was because I tried to use symlinks and that messed something up somehow. (Original question: Do you know why each and every word (including the ones spelled correctly) is now underlined after I activate the spell checker?)

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be a Linux user, symlinks help you implement the [accepted solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238852/) much faster.
I have done this with Ubuntu 16.04 and TeXworks 0.6.4.

#### Information

- Re **spell-chekers** and so, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell

  > **Hunspell** is based on **MySpell** and is backward-compatible with MySpell dictionaries. While MySpell uses a single-byte character encoding, Hunspell can use Unicode UTF-8-encoded dictionaries.
- Dictionaries are typically installed in **/usr/share**

  - Check with `ls /usr/share/*spell* -d` what they are. In my case, the directories are `aspell`, `hunspell`, `myspell`.
- TeXworks will want pairs of ***.aff *.dic files**.

  - So you can search with `find /usr/share/*spell* -name *dic | sort`. 
    These files are in hunspell and myspell directories.
  - I was lacking some. To get the catalogue, do `apt search hunspell-`; the trailing hyphen helps skimming the search results. You can then shortlist the packages you want from the locale tag, say `hunspell-pt-pt` for Portuguese of Portugal.
- TeXworks has it in section 4.3 **Spell-checking** of the **[manual](https://github.com/TeXworks/manual/releases)** that

  > Before using the spell-checker, you need to install dictionaries in the right folder of TeXworks: `[resources]\dictionaries`. The `[resources]` folder can be accessed easily via Help→Settings and Resources. . . .

  Linux users forgive the backward slash and those *folder* for *directory*. For me `[resources]` this is `~/home/user/.TeXworks`

#### Action

1. Install system-wide your preferred package(s) with `sudo install hunspell-[your choice]`.

   You will find that the directory list `ls /usr/share/hunspell` contains the aff/dic files of your choice now.
2. With `ln -s /usr/share/hunspell [resources]/dictionaries` I linked one-off the entity dictionaries to the full set of HunSpell dictionaries installed system-wide.

#### Benefit

Basically, any time I want a dictionary for TeXworks I install it from the HunSpell suite via the package management software.

I then find it up and running anywhere, and in TeXworks. I don't have to roam around the internet, rename, decompress and move around files.

#### Offnotes

Since Hunspell is a superset of MySpell, I got the Hunspell family of dictionaries in the `hunspell` directory even after installing the `myspell`-tagged packages

Answer (score 1):

You can download `en-GB.dic` and `en-GB.aff` dictionary files from https://github.com/hl-ren/Hunspell-TeXworks. `en_GB.dic` currently contains 87723 words.

In Windows 7, copy the files `en_GB.aff` and `en_GB.dic` to the path `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\hunspell\dicts\`.

Comment: Thank you for your revision :) @epr8gayuh