# Dowloading Latex Dictionaries

Tags: dictionaries

Do you guys recommend some link or site for downloading LaTeX dictionaries? Specifically, I need the Portuguese (Brazilian) one.

Comment: You are looking for a spell checker. LaTeX does not spell-check, never. You may find a LaTeX editor that includes spell-checking tough.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what "LaTeX dictionary" refers to. Therefore I will treat some possibilities:

- a way to tell LaTeX to use "Figura" instead of "Figure" (and the like), use the correct hyphenation rules and language-specific typographic rules etc. (see e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization). To accomplish this, packages like [babel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) (`\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}`) or [polyglossia](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) were created and already include their "dictionaries".
- a spell checker: While LaTeX itself does no spell checking, some LaTeX editors provide spell checking (and indeed need dictionaries to provide this feature), see for example: [How to add Spell Checker to TeXworks on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238852/6865).
- a dictionary in Brazilian and written in LaTeX (of course you would like to see the source code and not only the resulting pdf): While I am not aware of any freely available `BrazilianDictionary.tex`, the [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package could be useful (see also https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Multiple_columns) as well as the [thumbs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbs) package and of course [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) for cross-referencing.