# How to add Spell Checker to TeXworks on Mac?

Tags: mac, texworks, spelling

I am using TexWorks on my Mac but the spell-checking option is not active/available. In the spelling section, it shows "none".
There is a very closely related question in this community which can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235313/how-to-add-spell-checker-to-texworks-on-windows).

The answer to the question in the above link refers to a website that does not include any UK spell-checking dictionary, and I am interested in using a UK dictionary.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice
or this
https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/en

I search GB dictionaries.