# Italian spellcheck

Tags: texworks, spelling

I would like to load the italian spellchecker but it doesn't work. I followed some instructions found on the web and I downloaded the dictionary from this page http://linguistico.sourceforge.net/pages/dizionario_italiano.html and put them into the folder TexWorks\dictionaries. Now TexWorks recognizes the dictionary but it doesn't work (wrong words aren't underlined in red). What could have gone wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Did you apply the dictionary to the current file? It can be a bit tricky to get TeXworks to 'pick up' for the file you are work on when you first install the dictionary: Edit -> Spelling - > [Dictionary]

Comment: Yes, I selected the dictionary as you suggested but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using OsX, Windows or any Linux Operating System?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I tried this answer and worked under Window 7 with TeXworks 0.6.2.
[How to add Spell Checker to TeXworks on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235313/how-to-add-spell-checker-to-texworks-on-windows)

I use your dictionaries.
http://linguistico.sourceforge.net/pages/dizionario_italiano.html

I tried these dictionaries because they were fresher, but they did not work, all word underlined.
https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/it_IT

Comment: I tried also this method but it still doesn't work even though it recognizes the dictionary under Edit-Spelling.