# Is there any spell-check tool for LaTeX?

Tags: spell

I found some webpages but not helpful to me.
I'm using MikTex 2.9 with pdfTeX.
Thanks.

Comment: Which LaTeX software (Texmaker, TeXworks, TeXstudio, etc.) do you use?

Comment: Most LaTeX editors have spell-checking. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15/spell-checking-latex-documents

Comment: I'm now using the Latex->pdf->Word->spell check approach.

Comment: I was just aware of the function existed in my MikTeX installation. It's under Edit\Spelling. I just tried and it worked quite well. More features needed are another language setting (EN-UK) and the ability to add new words into the dictionary.

Comment: I found the dictionary from [https://extensions.openoffice.org/en] and here is how to install it - [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235313/how-to-add-spell-checker-to-texworks-on-windows]

Comment: And [how to add your words into the dictionary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235313/how-to-add-spell-checker-to-texworks-on-windows)