# How can I install scientific dictionaries to use with TeXworks?

Tags: texworks, spelling, dictionaries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TeXworks: How to add a word to the spell checker dictionary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11853/texworks-how-to-add-a-word-to-the-spell-checker-dictionary)

I frequently use terminology common in biology and chemistry, but not found in the hunspell dictionary. I have dictionaries in `.dic` format. Can I just add them to the hunspell dictionary or do I have to be sure the "new" list is alphabetized. Alternatively, is there a way to make TeXworks read the directory as is?

Comment: Perhaps [TeXworks: How to add a word to the spell checker dictionary?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11853/5764) is of help?

Comment: Does this help? http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/SpellingDictionaries

Comment: under Linux the files are in `/usr/share/myspell/`