# TeXStudio: Add new word to dictionary via button

Tags: texstudio, texworks, spelling, dictionaries

I installed a new Dutch dictionary from the Open Office website in my 'dictionaries' file. Spelling checks work perfectly in TeXStudio, but now, I'd like to add new words to the dictionary during the spelling check. I've already found this: [TeXworks: How to add a word to the spell checker dictionary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11853/texworks-how-to-add-a-word-to-the-spell-checker-dictionary/11861#11861).

However, that's not exactly what I want. Instead of editing the `.dic` and `.aff`. files manually, I'd like to provide a button, so that the new word is added to the dictionary automatically.

---

**Edit:**  What about adding a link to the spelling check box that opens the `.dic` and `.aff` files? Is that possible? I just want to avoid a long search for the files every time.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TeX.SX! I hope I got it right that you speak about TeXworks, so I added the appropriate information to the question ;) If it's not correct, you can hit the `edit` button and revert the changes. As to your question: I don't think it is possible in the current version of TeXworks.

Comment: Indeed, I'm working with the latest version of TeXStudio.

Comment: Since spelling checking is not a built in function of TeXworks or TeXstudio, I don't think it is possible, because TeXworks or/and TeXstudio search .dic and .aff files as database and check if there is a typo.

Comment: What do you mean by "add a link to the files"? Do you mean you want to put links, pointing to other files, in your PDF output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hunspell dictionaries (`.dic` and `.aff`) are more complex than just word lists (i.e. it contains information of possible affixes). Therefore, a proper entry cannot be generated from a single word.

The solution in TexStudio is to store additional words in an ignore word list (`.ign`) next to the dictionary. This list can be populated via `Context Menu -> always ignore` or via the `Always Ingore` button in the spell checking dialog.

Note: On Windows 7 the default dictionaries are in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\dictionaries\
```

Windows 7 prevents writing to the program files directory.It redirects the writes to User dictionaries, which are in

```
 C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\dictionaries
```

You may find the `.ign` files there.

Comment: On a Mac it looks like the added words are in /Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/Resources. This means that words added by the user are put in /Applications, which I would have thought is very non-standard.

Also, does this mean that if I have to reinstall TeXstudio for some reason all of the words I have added will be lost? Why aren't the added words in a file in ./config/texstudio, and could that be configured?

Comment: I wonder the same thing about the configuration...