# Resetting a dictionary in TexStudio/MikTeX

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I accidentally "always ignore"d a wrong wrong word. How do I undo it and make the old dictionary clean again?

Comment: Check if this helps you http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139930/14757 Try to edit some file and find the wrong word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see and edit the ignored words when you open `Tools -> Check spelling ...` and extend the dialog with the button "Show Ignore List":

[image: Extended spelling dialog]

The ignore list itself is stored in a file [language].ign alongside the dictionary files themselves. If you want to edit it directly, you should close TXS before. Otherwise your changes are not taken into account in the current session and may be overwritten on close.

Comment: For me the .ign file was located in `%appdata%\texstudio`, which is not in the same folder as the dictionary files themselves.