# TeXstudio - how to get access to the "added words" to dictionary?

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

By mistake, I have added a wrong word to the dictionary of TeXstudio. Now I cann't find where it is added. I have also tried to find the .ign file, but couldn't find such file in any folder. Please help how to get access to the words added to the dictionary of the TeXstudio. I have using Windows7 and TeXstudio 2.10.8.

Comment: see answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155887/resetting-a-dictionary-in-texstudio-miktex

Answer (score 28):

The easiest way to remove a word you added in the dictionary is: menu > Tools > Check spelling > Show user words > [select the unwanted word] > Remove

The `.ign` file should be located in the same folder as the dictionary you used to spell check. The folder is stated in  menu > Options > Configure TexStudio > Language checking > Spelling dictionary directories.
Once the ign file is found, you can edit it and remove the word you wrongly added.

Comment: I have tried this method, but in my case I want to add a bunch of words to the list. Turns out, whenever I add new words line by line in the `en_US.ign` file after the already existed ones, the new words always got removed the next time I add new words from TeXStudio. Any solution to add new words in a bunch?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I should close TeXStudio before adding new words to the list...

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04 with TeXstudio 2.10.8 the file with the ignored words is located in ~/.config/texstudio/ and named depending on the language something like texstudioen_GB.ign