# Where does TeXworks store list of words to be ignored by the spell checker

Tags: texworks, spelling, dictionaries

Where does TeXworks store words selected to be ignored by the spell checker? I am using TeXworks 0.4.5 r1280 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) on Win7 Enterprise 64-bit, with the Hunspell dictionary en_AU (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\hunspell\dicts).

Although I have selected several words to be ignored by the spell checker none of the hunspell dictionaries have been updated in several months. Thus I am wondering where does TeXworks store the list of words to be ignored by the spell checker?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11853/texworks-how-to-add-a-word-to-the-spell-checker-dictionary

Comment: Did you ever find this? I accidentally added a word to be ignored, and now I don't know how to remove it again.